# Search cell for text and copy text to another cell in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a column which contains rows that have parameters in them.  For example

W2 = [PROD][FO][2.0][Customer]

W3 = [PROD][GD][1.0][P3]

W4 = Issues in production for customer

I have a function that is copying other columns into another sheet, however for this column, I need to do the following

- Search the cell and look for [P*]
- The asterisk represents a number between 1 and 5
- If it finds [P*] then copy P* to the sheet "Calculations" in column 4
- Basically, remove everything from the cell except where there is a square bracket, followed by P, a number and a square bracket

Does anyone know how I can do this?  Alternatively, it might be easier to copy the column across and then remove everything that doesn't meet the above criteria.

Comment: What code do you have so far? You could use `Worksheetfunction.Search()`, or search for the exact strings.

Comment: All i've got so far is the code to copy a column to another sheet which works for those.  I've just added that it might be easier to copy that column across, and then remove all the text which isn't [P*] but I dont know where to start

Answer (score 1):

### Second Edit:

I edited here to use a regular expression instead of a loop. This may be the most efficient method to achieve your goal. See below and let us know if it works for you:

```
Function MatchWithRegex(sInput As String) As String
    Dim oReg As Object
    Dim sOutput As String

    Set oReg = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With oReg
        .Pattern = "[[](P[1-5])[]]"
    End With

    If oReg.test(sInput) Then
        sOutput = oReg.Execute(sInput)(0).Submatches(0)
    Else
        sOutput = ""
    End If

    MatchWithRegex = sOutput
End Function

Sub test2()
    Dim a As String

    a = MatchWithRegex(Range("A1").Value)


    If a = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "None"
    Else
        MsgBox MatchWithRegex(Range("A1").Value)
    End If
End Sub
```

### First EDIT:

My solution would be something as follows. I'd write a function that first tests if the Pattern exists in the string, then if it does, I'd split it based on brackets, and choose the bracket that matches the pattern. Let me know if that works for you.

```
Function ExtractPNumber(sInput As String) As String
    Dim aValues
    Dim sOutput As String

    sOutput = ""
    If sInput Like "*[[]P[1-5][]]*" Then
        aValues = Split(sInput, "[")
        For Each aVal In aValues
            If aVal Like "P[1-5][]]*" Then
                sOutput = aVal
            End If
        Next aVal
    End If

    ExtractPNumber = Left(sOutput, 2)
End Function


Sub TestFunction()
    Dim sPValue As String

    sPValue = ExtractPNumber(Range("A2").Value)

    If sPValue = vbNullString Then
        'Do nothing or input whatever business logic you want
    Else
        Sheet2.Range("A1").Value = sPValue
    End If
End Sub
```

### OLD POST:

In VBA, you can use the `Like` Operator with a Pattern to represent an Open Bracket, the letter P, any number from 1-5, then a Closed Bracket using the below syntax:

```
Range("A1").Value LIke "*[[]P[1-5][]]*"
```

Comment: How would I feed that into VBA to make it remove everything but that though

Comment: @K20GH See my edit and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Excellent.  This works.  Now I just need to figure out how to loop through each row/cell and then put the result into another cell

Comment: @K20GH That shouldn't be terribly difficult at all. If you find difficulty, create a new post with the specifics that are hindering you and I'm sure you'll get immediate help

Comment: Done :)  I've got a few issues but I think this is likely to do with the Regex. Appears like it fails to find the pattern if there is a space before or after the [P*]

Comment: Actually, I just tested it using a .NET Regex tester and its fine, yet it doesn't quite work in Excel.  Weird.

Comment: @K20GH For clarity, can you give an example of an input that has failed? I can test it to see if there's something odd with Excel.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Fixed faulty solution

If you're ok with blanks and don't care if *>5, I would do this and copy down column 4:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("[P?]",FirstSheet!$W2)), FirstSheet!$W2, "")
```

Important things to note:

- ? is the wildcard symbol for a single character; you can use * if you're ok with multiple characters at that location
- will display cell's original value if found, leave blank otherwise

Afterwards, you can highlight the column and remove blanks if needed. Alternatively, you can replace the blank with a placeholder string.

If * must be 1-5, use two columns, E and D, respectively:

```
=MID(FirstSheet!$W2,SEARCH("[P",FirstSheet!$W2)+2,1)
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER($E2),$E2>0,$E2<=5,MID($W2,SEARCH("[P",FirstSheet!$W2)+3,1))), FirstSheet!$W2, "")
```

where FirstSheet is the name of your initial sheet.